# is it possible to proccess JSON responses with the JDK or HttpComponents only?

Tags: json, java, facebook-graph-api, httpurlconnection

we are upgrading our web app to use Facebook's Graph API, which returns JSON responses. However we don't want to add dependecy to a JSON library unless we have no other choice. For server-side http requests we use Apache HttpComponents.

Thus, my question is what are the classes (if any) in the JDK and/or in HttpComponents that I can use to process JSON responses? Code snippets are welcome :)

Comment: What exactly is the rationale behind the "extra library" aversion? The core problem might have to be solved somewhere else.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, native JSON support [was delayed past Java 9](https://jaxenter.com/json-api-dropped-java-9-113028.html).

But for the sake of sportmanship here is plain Java 8 hacky solution using [Nashorn](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html) JavaScript engine without any external dependency:

```
String json = "{\"foo\":1, \"bar\":\"baz\"}";
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
Object o = engine.eval(String.format("JSON.parse('%s')", json));
Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) o;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(map.entrySet().toArray()));
// [foo=1, bar=baz]
```

[Since Java 8u60](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8130486) `JSON.parse` can be substituted with [`Java.asJSONCompatible`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/scripting/using-java-scripts.htm#JSJSG-GUID-12536D6E-1D76-4E05-8C74-DD7F44DFF167) which does better handling of JSON arrays.

Credits:

[Effective way to pass JSON between java and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31292201/effective-way-to-pass-json-between-java-and-javascript/31307873#31307873)

https://dzone.com/articles/mapping-complex-json-structures-with-jdk8-nashorn

Comment: This is great! My use case is a json is akin to "{\"message\" : \"{0}\"}", and I get the actual message from the user. can I somehow use nashorn to make the string into a proper json literal?

Comment: What is the difference between using "JSON.parse" and Java.asJSONCompatible as it is done here - http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/converting_json_to_map_with

Comment: @Jay, `Java.asJSONCompatible` does JSON array to Java List mapping. I've updated the answer. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: This sorted this out for me, thanks. For the other direction - generating valid json strings to be sent, I found this to work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56013134/get-a-proper-json-literal-in-java-8-using-nashorn

Comment: This does not work for json int value without quotation marks:
"expires_in":360,

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. Because JSON is valid JavaScript syntax, you can use the built-in JavaScript interpreter via the [scripting API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html) to create and object graph, walk that (using the visitor pattern to push data into a Java object, for example).

However, you need to trust the data or you leave yourself open to code injection attacks. To me, this would not be an adequate substitute for a proper JSON parser.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is the org.json package. You can get the source [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160107190249/http://www.json.org/java/) and simply include the handful of files in your project, it doesn't have any dependencies. This will allows you do create and parse JSON. The javadocs are well done and can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160107190249/http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/package-summary.html).

As an example, for consuming json, you can use a tokener and convert the raw string to a JSONObject. Then you can access the arrays by index or by key. You can access nested arrays by getting them as a JSONObject or JSONArray.

```
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(myJsonString);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(tokener);

String error = json.get("error");
int errorCode = json.getInt("error_code");

JSONArray messages = json.getJsonArray("messages");
```

Update:
The source is also available at [GitHub](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java)

Comment: The links are dead, do you think you can update them? Thanks.