# java nashorn parse json from file

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea, nashorn

I'm trying to parse a `json` file on my desktop using `java` and `intelliJ`. The googling I did seemed to bring up other `JSON`/`Java` API's and yet it seems `nashorn` comes with `intellij`, so I would rather try using that.

I can't figure it out however. I tried to adapt some code (`JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();`) but there was an error with an empty `JSONParser` declaration. How do I do it? I would like to save each `json` object as a java object (it is a `JSON` obj with 2 strings and an array and I'd like to preserve this structure).

Any help would be appreciated. I did look around but couldn't find the answer in a way that seemed applicable to this situation. Presumably I would still use `FileReader` to open the file. I've been using `BufferedReader` to read each line. Do I still use those with `JSON` files?

Thanks,
Rebecca

Comment: Here is a working code example of using nashorn to parse JSON: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43667674/603516. It may be useful for ad-hock scripts but not recommended for production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Nashorn` is not a `JSON` parser. It's a `Javascript` engine. If you want to parse `JSON` strings with Java, there are several good libraries. `Gson` and `Jackson` are popular examples.

To parse a `JSON` string into a Java object (deserialize), first you need to create the appropriate `type` (Java class). You pass this `type` as a parameter when you deserialize your `JSON`.

For example, with Gson:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyType myobject = gson.fromJson(jsonSource, MyType.class);
```

Comment: Could you explain what the JSONParser class in Nashorn does, then?

Answer (score 2):

To provide a more relevant answer than "use something else", the Nashorn runtime has `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` just like nodejs.
So, load the file in java (since you will have to load the file using java classes in nashorn anyway), and once you have a string representation of your file, call it `script`, and an instance of `ScriptEngine`, call it `engine`, just call eval and get the result like so: `Object parsed = engine.eval("JSON.parse("+script+")";)` and `parsed` will contain the parsed json, since `eval` returns the result of the last expression

This is only as useful as a Anonymous `Object` however, and will need to be handled in Java. You can also parse the json in nashorn and create a java object in nashorn (or just handle the data in nashorn), but this will require you to write a nashorn script.

Good Luck!

Reference:

[ScriptEngine JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#eval-java.lang.String-)

[A good nashorn tutorial](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiVjrjgy-ztAhVSpZ4KHUDFCjwQFjABegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.baeldung.com%2Fjava-nashorn&usg=AOvVaw1BXE84Sq3k0Z_HUWb6fqw4)

[Reading a file in Java](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiioryDzOztAhXKvp4KHaaYAQsQFjACegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.baeldung.com%2Freading-file-in-java&usg=AOvVaw0LROt3hc2BrbdYBT9jOQ7t)