# Cannot use JSONObject and JSONException in openjdk-1.8.0

Tags: json, fedora, java

I am trying to create a test JSON validator in Java (on Fedora 27), but I cannot import JSON-related packages. Do different Java implementations use different packages for this purpose?
My source code is as follows:

```
import javax.json.JsonObject; 
import javax.json.JsonException;

public class JsonParsing {
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        String str = "<h1>This is a test.</h1>";
        if(isValidJson(str)) {
               System.out.println("Valid JSON");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("JSON Exception detected");
        }

    }
    private static boolean isValidJson(String response) {
        try{ 
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject (response);
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            System.out.println("JSONException");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Error log:

> JsonParsing.java:2: error: package javax.json does not exist import
>   javax.json.Json;
>                    ^ JsonParsing.java:3: error: package javax.json does not exist import javax.json.JsonObject;
>                    ^ JsonParsing.java:18: error: cannot find symbol         JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject (response);         ^   symbol:
>   class JSONObject   location: class JsonParsing JsonParsing.java:18:
>   error: cannot find symbol         JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject
>   (response);
>                                  ^   symbol:   class JSONObject   location: class JsonParsing JsonParsing.java:19: error: cannot find symbol        }
>   catch(JSONException e) {
>                 ^   symbol:   class JSONException   location: class JsonParsing 5 errors

Comment: use `json-simple-1.1.1.jar`. It provides required class to work with JSON.

Comment: Do you have the required jars in your class path ?

Comment: Do you have standard jars for json on place?

Comment: No I don't have any jars. Isn't JSON in Java already? Do I need to add external libraries?

Answer (score 2):

include the following dependency in your "pom.xml" file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Isn't this a different library for working with json? Doesn't the Java SDK library has its own json classes?

Comment: You can find your answer here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970195/is-it-possible-to-proccess-json-responses-with-the-jdk-or-httpcomponents-only

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is, you don't have those classes in scope.

This package is not one of the standard java libraries included in your java environment, all you need to do is to find the required jar and ensure it is in scope.

Answer (score 0):

The javax.json package is not part of Java SE. You can find the Java SE API for Java SE 9 at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/overview-summary.html .

You need to add an additional library which implements the javax.json API to your classpath or module path. That JSON-P API was developed as part of JSR 353: https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=353 .